# I need help proving this theorem (composition of functions)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

This is the statement:

> If $f$ and $g$ are functions, the composition $g\circ f$ is a function with $$D(g\circ f)=\{x\in D(f):f(x)\in D(g)\}$$
>   $$R(g\circ f)=\{g(f(x)):x\in D(g\circ f)\}$$

The first part (to prove that $g\circ f$ is a function) is easy, but I don't know how to proceed on the second part. Please, any help would be really appreciated.

$D(f)$ denotes the domain of $f$ and $R(f)$ denotes the range of $f$.

Comment: How are you defining the composition?  Most definitions I see simply use those very statements as their definition...

Comment: This looks like a definition to me as well. There is nothing to prove.

Comment: As an aside, you're really composing them as if they were *partial* functions. (which, in a sense, is true as any function on a set can be viewed not only as a partial function on that set, but also as a partial functions on the class of all sets... but the point is you're composing them as partial functions rather than as functions)

Comment: My book say it's a thorem. $g\circ f$ is the set of all $(a,c)\in A\times C$ such that there exists a $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in f$ and $(b, c)\in g$

Comment: The statement in your comment **is** a theorem. The statement in your OP is a definition that can be used to prove this theorem.

Comment: Oh, my book uses it as a definition.

Comment: okay, the other way around then. Either way, your OP is missing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$D(g\circ f)=\{x\in D(f):f(x)\in D(g)\}$$

Let $x$ be in the domain of $g\circ f$. Then $(g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))$, so $f(x)$ needs to be in the domain of $g$, and $x$ in the domain of $f$.

> $$R(g\circ f)=\{g(f(x)):x\in D(g\circ f)\}$$

Let $x$ be in the domain of $g\circ f$. Then the image of $x$ will be $(g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))$.

Comment: Oh, it was easy...thanks!